# Is there a way to apply CSS to all HTML5 textual inputs, regardless of type attribute?

Tags: css, html

Given these HTML inputs of differing `types`:

```
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="email" id="emailaddress" />
<input type="date" id="birthday" />
<input type="password" id="pword" />
<input type="search" id="q" />
```

Is it possible to apply CSS styles to all **text boxes** without having to either add a class to each or selecting them like this:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"]
...
```

Also I don't want to use `input { }` as that would select radio buttons etc. when I only want to style are the text boxes.

Comment: There is no other way, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. For instance, it's up to the browser to decide how an input is rendered. There's no way to query how the browser has rendered a control (as far as I know).
For example, some browsers will render a 'range' input as as textbox rather than a slider. Also some browsers render the 'search' control differently to other text boxes (rounded corners etc), so your CSS may not work as you expect anyway.

I think you'll have to go for the input[type="text"], input=[type="password"] { } rules as you described.

Comment: I think you are correct, there is no way to target textboxes in general regardless of type attribute. It would be nice if you could though!

Answer (score 3):

Either

```
input {...}
input[type="radio"] { (undo changes here) }
```

or

```
input:not([type="radio"]) {...}
```

While the later may look more straightforward, take note that not all browsers support the `not` syntax yet.

Comment: Agreed—and I'd probably go with the first option for wider browser support. See 10 thru 16 and 20 in this link: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: Hm, I see I probably misinterpreted the OP's question, in that the types `button`, `reset`, `image`, `checkbox`, etc shouldn't be styled either! So I tend more to agree with Ben's answer now.